# How to get rid of the extra space on ControlTemplate for button XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, button, controltemplate, blend

I am creating a custom Button using Blend for Visual Studio 2013. As you can see from the image, there is an extra space on the right and left of the button which I can't get rid of. This originates from the ControlTemplate tag.
[image]

The width for controls inside the template such as Grid, BottomRect, TopRect, ContentPresenter etc can be adjusted without problem. Dragging the blue rectangle  for ControlTemplate  doesn't work.

I assume I need to somehow override the default Width property of the ControlTemplate but how do it? Thanks.

Comment: if you download http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ and check your program you will be able to see (via the adorners) where the extra space is coming from. To me, this looks like a padding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin of the grid

```
....
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="0" ...
    ...
```

EDITED

Ok, then you can use TemplateBinding

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonGameStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="42" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="42" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    ...
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then you can set width, height and margin in your buttons

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonGameStyle}" Width="20" Height="20" />
```

Comment: Didn't fix the ControlTemplate width.

Comment: When you set properties in both the style and the control itself, the properties in the control *override* the styles setters. Having them defined in both the style and the control is redundant.